# Problems with accessing HashMaps from other classes

Tags: java, hashmap, bukkit

I am writing a plugin using Spigot (pretty much Bukkit) but I'm having problems accessing a HashMap from one class in another. Here is my HashMap and getter:

```
private Map<String, Integer> compPlayers = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public Map<String, Integer> getCompPlayers(){
    return compPlayers;
}
```

I am able to see if the HashMap contains certain keys from within the class such as here:

```
if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("join")){
    if(compPlayers.containsKey(p.getName())){
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are already part of the competition");
        return false;
    }
```

yet in my listener class, I can't seem to access it properly. Here's a section of code in my listener class:

```
public class CompetitionListener implements Listener {

private PluginMain plugin;

public CompetitionListener(PluginMain plugin){
    this.plugin = plugin;
}

@EventHandler
public void onBlockPlace(BlockBreakEvent e){
        Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
        p.sendMessage("BlockBreakEvent");
        if(plugin.getCommands().getCompPlayers().containsKey(p.getName())){
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You scored a point!");
            plugin.getCommands().getCompPlayers().put(p.getName(), plugin.getCommands().getCompPlayers().get(p.getName() + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

PluginMain is the class that extends JavaPlugin and getCommands() is a getter for the Commands class from within it.

Though I am able to access all these methods from the listener class without errors, the line checking if the player name is in the HashMap doesn't work and always returns false. The event itself does work.

Comment: I forgot to add-- the HashMap is in the Commands class.

Comment: Print out the map when the event is called, make sure that the player is in there.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is no information. Specify the expected behaviour and include the actual behaviour.

Comment: @Unihedron I had said that the if statement in the listener class always returns false no matter what the HashMap contains. Obviously I want it returning true if the player name is in the HashMap.

Comment: @kmecpp the player is definitely stored in the HashMap. When calling for scores (inside the Commands class that contains the HashMap) the value stored under the key (the player name) is printed out.

Comment: Are you *putting* the username or UUID into the map? Also, try making all of the contents lowercase. If its neither of those things, try printing out the player's name, and the contents of the HashMap in your onBlockPlace method

Comment: Try adding the static modifier to the map, so you won't create a new map everytime

Comment: **SOLVED**
I had different instances of the class and the listener used a new instance where obviously there would be nothing in the HashMap as everything had been stored in the other instance.

Answer (score 1):

You never register the events in your `Listener` class.

In your `Listener` class's constructor, add the following:

```
plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
```